# Firebase order and limit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I fetch from a specific collection and it have more than 100 values and I want to order them by rank. I've a rank field. Where do I put the order and limit in the following code.

```
useEffect(
    () =>
      onSnapshot(collection(db, "collectiondb/id/users"), (snapshot) =>
        setLeaders(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
      ),
    []
  );
```

Here is how it's going to output it.

```
  const [leaders, setLeaders] = useState([{ name: "Loading...", id: "initial" }]);
```

```
<ul type='1'>
        {leaders.map((leader) => (
          <li>
              {leader.rank} {leader.name} </>
          </li>
        ))}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`.orderBy`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) this way:

```js
collection(db, 'collectiondb/id/users')
.orderBy('rank')
.orderBy('createdDate', 'desc')
.limit(100)
```

Edit: Solution by OP:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const collectionRef = collection(db, 'collectiondb/id/users');
  const q = query(collectionRef, limit(10), where('rank', '>', 0), orderBy('rank', 'asc'));
  const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => setLeaders(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(),
    id: doc.id
  }))));
  return unsub;
}, []);
```

Comment: It's not working that way. I'm using useEffect. Or is there a better way just to fetch from firebase without useEffect.

Comment: @hello is it giving any error with this?

Comment: it's not showing me the results, can you show me where I'll put that exactly in my code? I'm probably messing something with the useEffect.

Comment: @hello you could try accessing it this way `db.collection('collectiondb/id/users').orderBy('rank').limit(100).onSnapshot((snapshot) =>{}))` [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

Comment: I figured it out now, thanks

Comment: @hello do add answer for this question, it would be helpful for others

Comment: ```
useEffect(() => {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'collectiondb/id/users');
    const q = query(collectionRef,limit(10),where('rank', '>', 0),orderBy('rank', 'asc'));

    const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) =>
    setLeaders(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
    );

    return unsub;
}, []);
```